# force remount on value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mount

I have some files that builds a cart in a dropdown for my shop website.

One file adds the selected item to an array which will be my cart. The other file is the `CartDropdown` component itself. My cart only show the items when I close and open it (remounting), but I want it to remount every time I add a new item.

Adding item function:

```
const ProductContainer = ({ productInfo }) => {
  const { cartProducts, setCartProducts } = useContext(CartContext);
  const cartArray = cartProducts;

  const addProduct = () => {
    productInfo.quantity = 1;
    if (cartArray.includes(productInfo)) {
      const index = cartArray.findIndex((object) => {
        return object === productInfo;
      });
      cartProducts[index].quantity++;
      setCartProducts(cartArray);
    } else {
      cartArray.push(productInfo);
      setCartProducts(cartArray);
    }
    // setCartProducts(cartArray)
    console.log(cartProducts);
    // console.log(cartArray)
  };
};
```

dropdown component

```
const CartDropdown = () => {
  const { setCartProducts, cartProducts } = useContext(CartContext);
  const { setProducts, currentProducts } = useContext(ProductsContext);
  // useEffect(() => {}, [cartProducts])
  const cleanCart = () => {
    const cleanProducts = currentProducts;
    console.log(cleanProducts);
    for (let i in cleanProducts) {
      if (cleanProducts[i].hasOwnProperty("quantity")) {
        cleanProducts[i].quantity = 0;
      }
    }
    setProducts(cleanProducts);
    setCartProducts([]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="cart-dropdown-container">
      <div className="cart-items">
        {cartProducts.map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id}>
            <img src={product.imageUrl}></img>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={cleanCart}>CLEAN CART</button>
      <Button children={"FINALIZE PURCHASE"} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I force the dropdown to remount every time `cartProducts` changes?

CART CONTEXT:

```
    export const CartContext = createContext({
    isCartOpen: false,
    setIsCartOpen: () => { },
    cartProducts: [],
    setCartProducts: () => { }
})

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isCartOpen, setIsCartOpen] = useState(false)
    const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState([])
    const value = { isCartOpen, setIsCartOpen, cartProducts, setCartProducts };
    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

product context

```
    export const ProductsContext = createContext({
    currentProducts: null,
    setProducts: () => {}
})

export const ProductsProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [currentProducts, setProducts] = useState(shop_data)
    const value = {currentProducts, setProducts} 

    return(
        <ProductsContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ProductsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your probably need to provide your context provider and consumer code as well for anyone to get a better understanding on what is not working.

Comment: just updated it

Answer (score 0):

You can change the key prop of the component every time you want to remount. Every time `cartProduct` changes, update the value of key. You can do that using a useEffect with cartProduct as a dependency.

```
<CartDropdown key={1} />
```

to

```
<CartDropdown key={2} />
```

**Edit for more clarification:**

```
const [keyCount, setKeyCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    setKeyCount(keyCount+1);
}, [cartProducts]);

<CartDropdown {...otherProps} key={keyCount} />
```

Comment: let forceRemount = 1
   useEffect(() => {
    forceRemount += 1
   },[cartProducts])


<CartDropdown key={forceRemount}

Like this?

Comment: that would probably work well, but didnt. In fact, if i do usestate(console.log('A'), [cartProducts]) its not triggering everytime i add my cart product

Comment: That could be because cartProducts reference is not changing every time, hence useEffect might not get triggered. I suggest to use a more appropriate check (cartProducts.quantity or cartProducts.length or something else) based on what works for you, but this approach should work. You just need to figure out based on what you want to re-mount your component.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is that you are not using the callback to set the state inside the context but you are doing `cartProducts[index].quantity++` and [react docs specify](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

> Do Not Modify State Directly

Also after `cartProducts[index].quantity++`, you call `setCartProducts(cartArray);` not with `cartProducts` which you actually updated (this is also the reason why `"if I do usestate(console.log('A'), [cartProducts]) its not triggering everytime i add my cart product"`. But  anyway there is an issue even if you would use `cartArray` for both:

You shouldn't directly do `const cartArray = cartProducts` since by doing so `cartArray` will be a reference to `cartProducts` (not a copy of it) which also shouldn't be modified (because it would mean that you are modifying state directly).

So first 2 things I recommend you to improve would be:

1. Initialize `cartArray` as a `cartProducts` deep copy (if your `cartProducts` is an array of objects, spread syntax won't do it). So I would reccomand you to check [this question answers for creating a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).
2. After you make sure that `cartArray` is a deep copy of `cartProducts`, doublecheck you use `cartArray` to create a local newValue then set the state of the context with the same value (so basically:

```
      cartArray[index].quantity++;
      setCartProducts(cartArray);
```

)

3. The deep copy part also apply for `const cleanProducts = currentProducts;` (you should also create a deep copy here for `cleanProducts`, instead of saving the object ref).

If you are not using deep copies, your code might still work in some cases, but you might encounter weird behaviors in some other instances (and thoose are really hard to debug). Therefore is a bad practice in general not using deep copies.